# PHP, AJAX, TINYmce POST with special Characters ÆØÅ not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, tinymce

I have a problem with special characters æøå when posting. 
I have searched the web, and cant fint anything thats related.

My AJAX looks like this:

```
    function savep(str){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "savep.php";
    var text = document.getElementById("myarea").value=tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
     var vars = "id="+str+"&text="+text;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState === 4 && hr.status === 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
//    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<img src='../pics/process.gif' width='32' height='32'>";
}
```

What i have found out is that when it goes threw the JAVA it doenst post the special characters.

My PHP looks like this:

```
<?php
include('../session/session.php');



if(isset($_POST['id'])&& !empty($_POST['text'])){


 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $cont = $_POST['text'];
       error_log($cont);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE pages SET content=:cont where id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':cont',$cont, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $pchange = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($pchange > 0)
    {

        echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Adgangskoden er ændret</div>";
          $conn = null;
    } else
    {
        echo  "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Adagangskoden blev ikke ændret</div>";
          $conn = null;
    }

    } else
    {

         echo  "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Det indstastede kodeord er forkert!</div>";
          $conn = null;
    }




?>
```

And finally the page where it all comes from:

```
<?php
include ("../session/session.php");
include ("../include/dbconn.php");
if(isset($_GET['id'])&& !empty($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];



    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id= :id ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $edit = $stmt->fetchAll();

   foreach($edit as $row)
   {
        $title = $row['title'];
        $cont = $row['content'];
       echo $title;
   }    


}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
     <link rel="icon" href=".../pics/favicon.ico">

    <title>Dashboard Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js'></script>
     <script src="../js/userfunc.js"></script>
      <script>

  tinymce.init({
     selector: '.text2',
    theme: 'modern',
    width: "800",
    height: "300",
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
  ],
  toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
  image_advtab: true

  });
  </script>

  </head>

  <body>
        <?php include ("navbar.php") ?>

        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h1 class="page-header">Edit <?php echo $title; ?></h1>

              <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="well">
                      <textarea class='text2' id='myarea'> <?php echo $cont; ?> </textarea> <br>
               <button  name='save' id='save' class='btn btn-success' onclick="savep(<?php echo $id; ?>)" > Save </button>

               <div id="status">

                  </div>  
              </div>


        </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
    <script src="../js/holder.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, when i have written somthing in the textarea, and presses the button, it runs something through the AJAX, but Æ Ø Å doesnt get in the database. When i insert manually into the DB and reads from it it works like a charm.

I have tried to figure out the problem. But i can not figure it out.

Comment: you could before saving your editor content recode the characters into html entties